# Lean golf: Balanced Bracket Sequence

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string, proof-golf, lean

> **Ungolfed, ugly, horrible proof to help you make progress on this challenge: https://gist.github.com/huynhtrankhanh/dff7036a45073735305caedc891dedf2**

A bracket sequence is a string that consists of the characters `(` and `)`. There are two definitions of a balanced bracket sequence.

### Definition 1

- The empty string is balanced.
- If a string x is balanced, `"(" + x + ")"` is also balanced.
- If x and y are two balanced strings, `x + y` is also balanced.

### Definition 2

The balance factor of a string is the difference between the number of `(` characters and the number of `)` characters. A string is balanced if its balance factor is zero and the balance factor of every prefix is nonnegative.

Your task is to prove the two definitions are equivalent in the [Lean theorem prover](https://leanprover-community.github.io), specifically Lean 3. You're allowed to use the mathlib library.

Formalized statement:

```
inductive bracket_t
| left
| right

inductive balanced : list bracket_t → Prop
| empty : balanced []
| wrap (initial : list bracket_t) : balanced initial → balanced ([bracket_t.left] ++ initial ++ [bracket_t.right])
| append (initial1 initial2 : list bracket_t) : balanced initial1 → balanced initial2 → balanced (initial1 ++ initial2)

def balance_factor : ∀ length : ℕ, ∀ string : list bracket_t, ℤ
| 0 _ := 0
| _ [] := 0
| (n + 1) (bracket_t.left::rest) := 1 + balance_factor n rest
| (n + 1) (bracket_t.right::rest) := -1 + balance_factor n rest

def balance_factor_predicate (string : list bracket_t) := balance_factor string.length string = 0 ∧ ∀ n : ℕ, n < string.length → 0 ≤ balance_factor n string

lemma X (string : list bracket_t) : balanced string ↔ balance_factor_predicate string := begin
  -- your proof here
  sorry,
end
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins.

**How to solve this challenge:**

- The `balanced string -> balance_factor_predicate` part can be solved relatively easily by "running at it"—do induction on the `balanced string` predicate, keep your head, and you are done.
- The `balance_factor_predicate -> balanced string` part is slightly harder. I used well founded recursion to prove this part. I cleverly mimicked each constructor of the `balanced` predicate and stitched the constructors together with well founded recursion. Read the complete proof for more details.

Remember to ping me in chat (The Nineteenth Byte or The Lean-to) if you need help. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to constrain the `length` parameter in `balance_factor` to actually be equal to the length of `string`? Or maybe it could be implemented as `sum(map foofun string)` or something like that?